# Using pipes with find command in linux

Tags: linux, bash, unix, pipe

I would like to find files in my home directory that start with '~', sort them numerically, print the first five and delete them using find command and pipes in Linux. I have a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
find ~/ -name "~*" | sort -n | head -5 | tee | xargs rm
```

This works fine for deleting files, but I was expecting `tee` command to print deleted files to standard output. All this command does is delete files, but there in so output in terminal. What should I add/ change?
Thank you.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `tee` command?

Comment: You do understand that a pipe consumes stdout, right?

Comment: I do understand that pipe connects stdout of first command with stdin of the second yes, but I thought it was possible to somehow prevent that with `tee` command since it was a tip I got at the lectures...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use the verbose flag on rm and it will tell you what it's deleting

```
find ~/ -name "~*" | sort -n | head -5 |  xargs rm -v
```

Use `man rm` to see the docs

> -v, --verbose
>
> explain what is being done

Comment: I used this solution since it is short and does exactly what I imagined :) Thank you.

Comment: No problem, glad I can help :).

Comment: Yes it is short but use it only if you are 100% sure that filenames won't contain whitespace or glob characters.

Comment: Yeah true white spaces can be tricky, however i was just making as few changes as possible to the original code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `rm -v` to print each deleting filename:

```
find ~ -name '~*' -print0 | sort -zn | head -z -n 5 | xargs -0 rm -v
```

Also note use `-print0` and all corresponding options in `sort. head, xargs` to address filenames with whitespace and glob characters.

Comment: Never knew that `head` supports the `-z` flag

Comment: I believe only gnu `head` supports `-z`